# Why does Android Studio recommend "Move to top level"?

Tags: android, kotlin, object

I have a class for a ToolBar (ToolBarView.kt), which inside has an object "object ToolbarBinding { ...". Inside this object, I have:

[image: Kotlin code snippet]

Android Studio advises me to "Move to top level" and when I do it, it appears like this:

[image: Kotlin code snippet]

```
With this, so that there is no error, I remove "@JvmStatic". But, I don't understand why it advises me to "Move to top level" nor why when I move it, I have to remove "@JvmStatic".

  Thanks for the answers in advance :)
```

I have searched the web for similar cases and queries but I have not found an answer

Comment: I could be wrong. But I believe it's not necessarily an advice, it's just a context action you can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Android Studio does not highlight your method signature with the yellow wavy underline or a yellow background, then it is probably not an advice but rather a shortcut for an action which can be commonly done by developers in cases like this (but it is not necessarily **needed**).

As far as I know, recommendations and advices provided by IDE have left hand icon looking like a lamp:

[image]

And plain context actions that are there just for convenience look like this:

[image]

One more example:

[image]